# How do i check whether the url is responsive or not

Tags: asp.net

I have Image Url in my Database and i want to check whether the URL is responsive or not in the browser .
please Help me .
For Example :
http://images.jactravel.co.uk/6008_1_1.jpg
or
http://images.jactravel.co.uk/6049_2_4.jpg

now how can i check automatically this url is responsive or not

Comment: I think you mix up some concepts here - what do you mean "responsive"?

Comment: Not understand your question exactly

Comment: Do you mean, whether you can get a response for that URL? Try to download it

Comment: responsive mean whether the url is responding or not(page does't exist  ,404error )

Comment: i mean i want to check whether the url is exist or not , without download it .

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by `responsive` you mean whether you can get a response when you call a specific URL or not.

To do that without actually downloading the content, you can use the [HttpClient.GetAsync(string,HttpCompletionOption)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551757(v=vs.118).aspx) with an HttpCompletionOption of [ResponseHeadersRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcompletionoption(v=vs.118).aspx). This will make `GetAsync` return immediately with a status code (eg 200, 404 or 500) without waiting to download the entire content, eg:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using(var response = await client.GetAsync("http://mysite/myimage.jpg",
                                            HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //The URL is good
        }
    }
}
```

To actually read the content, you need to access one of the `Read` methods of the response's [Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent(v=vs.118).aspx) property. For example, you can use the [CopyToAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138076(v=vs.118).aspx) to copy the content to a file stream, or use [ReadAsByteArrayAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasbytearrayasync(v=vs.118).aspx) to read the content as a byte array, eg:

```
var buffer=await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

Comment: But i am getting error he 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<bool>'   Please tell me how can i solve this error.